# Adding an int, a byte, a long, and a float

Tags: java

If you try to add an `int`, a `byte`, a `long`, and a `float`, what kind of data type is the result? (`float`, `long`, `byte`, `int` or is it even possible?)

Comment: What do you think it is? Do you think we should do your homework for you?

Comment: I agree, if you're asking if it's possible why don't you try and see for yourself?

Comment: the result data type is "CockTail"

Comment: I don't know why this question was closed. This is a valid question. Particularly to systems engineering students.

Comment: @SemereTazazSium: check the reason why it was closed below.

Comment: Well i'm assuming since float can hold the most data it would be a float, I'm just making sure since I've just learned this and was making sure something weird wouldnt happen

Comment: Matt I'll repeat Semere's question, as I dont think it should have been closed either.  It's a real question, it's NOT a matter of opinion and understanding the answer means learning a little bit about internal representations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the order of your expression and any type casts you make.  However, unless you know something special about the requirements of the computatino, it had *better* be a float or a double; anything less will truncate the digits after the decimal.

Comment: That makes sense! I was over analyzing the question, thanks